OpenStack ovs: Multiple rows in Manager patch "ptcp:6640:127.0.0.1"
While setting up OpenStack following the instructions on https://docs.openstack.org/2024.1/install/ I encounter an error on the netron-ovs-agent service. It wont start and shows the error message
multiple rows in Manager patch "ptcp:6640:127.0.0.1"

I checked the ovs database dump, which shows only one row in the Manager table. Configuration wise I followed the minimal installation guide to the best of my knowledge. But other than mentioned in the instructions, I'm setting up OpenStack on one server instead of two.
How can I get the neutron-ovs-agent to run properly and resolve the aforementioned error?
